# Is there a way to see how many request are done per API key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm curious if there is a way to see how many requests are made per API key in my Google Cloud Platform account. First, there was a number specified for the last 30 days at every key.

How to see which keys aren't used anymore, or which make countless requests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to view request count per API key, you may use **[Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/)**.

1. First, in your google cloud console's navigation menu, go to **Monitoring > Metrics Explorer**.
2. In the *Resource Type*, select "Consumed API" in order to view the APIs used by the account.
3. In the *Metric*, select "Request Count".
4. In the *Group by*, select "credential_id" to group the results by API Key.
5. In the *Minimum alignment period*, select "Custom".
6. In the *Period Value*, input "30".
7. In the *Period Unit*, select "days".

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- You may change the *Period Unit* based on your desired period unit but please note that the *Period Value* must follow the change on *Period Unit*.
- You may change the *Aggregator* to "count" for the exact count the API key was used on the selected period or use another aggregator based on your desired results.

Final configuration will look similar to this:

[image: Final Conifguration]

Comment: This is exactly where I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Greetings from 2023! It appears that GCP has reorganized its metrics fields somewhat. I stumbled around a bit and used this answer for reference, and did get it to work. Of note is that "Custom" is no longer an option; however, you *can* type "30d" into the field and it will honor that.